# Error when trying to open file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I've created a `txt` file by Microsoft Word and saved it as `texta.txt` in a folder `untitled`. I've also saved a python file as `texti.py` in the same folder `untitled`.

When going back to Wing IDE, i typed the following:

```
infile = open('texta.txt')
lines = infile.readlines()
```

and it returned:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 2, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 192: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i want to open the file (text), and print it into the python shell.

Comment: Are you sure it's really a plain-text file, or is it a doc file that just happens to have the `txt` extension? Also, you might want to check the encoding of the file and use `open('texta.txt', encoding="some encoding")`

Comment: Yes. when i finish writing the text on M.word, i click save as, and then it asks me which format, i click: "Plain Text (.txt)".
i have used the endcoding as well, it returned: `builtins.LookupError: unknown encoding: some encoding`

Comment: Well, you should not _literally_ put `"some encoding"` there, but the encoding the file actually has. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Open the file with a decent text editor to find out which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file as .txt, you should specify the encoding instead of letting the editor choose for you, and not tell you.  LibreOffice has two text SaveAs options: 'Text (.txt)' and 'Text - choose encoding (.txt)'.  MS Word should also have an option to select the encoding.  If not, get an editor that does.  And select UTF8 unless you have a reason to select otherwise.

The particular error message suggests to me that your text file is not utf8. A likely alternative is 'latin1'.  If so, `b'\xd5'.decode('latin1') == 'Õ'`.  If 'Õ' is the 195th char in your file, use `encoding=latin1`.  If not, you could guess something else.  Or reopen with MS Word on the same machine and save with a known encoding.